# Can't connect with Database.Open("MySQLConnection") - The server was not found or was not accessible

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, razor

I'm trying to make chart/graph in ASP.NET in Visual Studio based on results in the database and I'm having problems with connecting to database with `Database.Open().` 
I'm getting error:

> SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific
>   error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The
>   server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance
>   name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not
>   open a connection to SQL Server)

I'm using MySQL and the database is online (even though I tried with local db and I'm  getting the same error)

I found this kind of creating graphs here:  http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/data/7-displaying-data-in-a-chart

This is the code in .cshtml

```
@using WebMatrix.Data;
@{
    var db = Database.Open("MySQLConnection");
    var data = db.Query("SELECT user_IP, user_Country FROM user_stats");
    var myChart = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400)
        .AddTitle("Naslov")
        .DataBindTable(dataSource: data, xField: "userIP")
        .Write();
}
```

Here is connection string I'm using in `Web.config` (I removed real username and password here)

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="MySQLConnection"
     connectionString="Server=46.105.103.40;Database=miranzab_webtrafficanalyzer;Uid=username;Pwd=password;"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

P.S. I've read about this kind of exceptions and usually there's a problem with connection string, but I'm using that same connection string without any problems for connecting to databse in other parts of application (In Models and Controllers) and it works fine...though I'm using this for connecting:

```
cWebTrafficDb checkUserStatsWrapper = new cWebTrafficDb();  //this class is for opening and closing connections
checkUserStatsWrapper.cmd.CommandText = string.Format("select * from user_stats where user_ip = '{0}'", userIp);
MySqlDataReader reader = checkUserStatsWrapper.cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

P.S.S I am using MySql and I've changed provider name as few users said it might be the problem... The error was the same.

toddmo thank you very much. this finally got to the connection string. but now I'm having problems with it too lol...I was getting error like `System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'server'`. and the same for 'database' property in connection string and then I googled for error and it seems that I had to change connection string to this `<add name="MySQLConnection" connectionString="Data Source=46.105.103.40;Initial Catalog=miranzab_webtrafficanalyzer;Integrated Security=SSPI;User Id=username;Password=password" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />`

Here is the whole Web.config file:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
 
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MySQLConnection"
      connectionString="Data Source=46.105.103.40;Initial Catalog=miranzab_webtrafficanalyzer;Integrated Security=SSPI;User Id=username;Password=password;"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
    
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Try this without the quotes:
var db = Database.Open("MySQLConnection");
IOW:
var db = Database.Open(MySQLConnection);

Comment: MySql ? Then why you use the Provider for Sql Server?

Comment: Change your providerName to _providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"_

Comment: @Steve, I think he means "My Sql Connection", like "My Variable", "My Class", etc.

Comment: Which one r u using ? Is it MySQL or SqlServer ?

Comment: Could you please whole code, so that we can trace out where exactly it went wrong ?

Comment: He says _I'm using MySQL and the database is online_ . It seems that there is a basic problem here.

Comment: I'm using MySQL and probably put wrong providerName, but even when I changed it , it was the same error, user toddmo fixed it but I'm still getting error with connection strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to include `using System.Configuration;` in your code module and 
change `Database.Open("MySQLConnection");` to `Database.OpenConnectionString(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MySQLConnection"].ConnectionString);`

In the first attempt, it is literally looking at `MySQLConnection` as if it was the connection string. You need to replace the key (MySQLConnection) with the connection string that goes along with that key.

Comment: I needed to put `@using System.Configuration;` but now I'm getting error: `Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Connection string "Server=46.105.103.40;Database=miranzab_webtrafficanalyzer;Uid=username;Pwd=password;" was not found.`

Comment: toddmo thank you very much. this finally got to the connection string. but now I'm having problems with it too lol...I was getting error like  `System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'server'.` and the same for 'database' property in connection string and then I googled for error and it seems that I had to change connection string to this `<add name="MySQLConnection" connectionString="Data Source=46.105.103.40;Initial Catalog=miranzab_webtrafficanalyzer;Integrated Security=SSPI;User Id=username;Password=password"
         providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />`

Comment: but I'm still getting the same erorr for 'Initial Catalog'

Comment: Well, if it's sql server, change the provider back to sql server